# Is there a git command to pull origin/master then rebase the working branch?

Tags: git

My git workflow involves frequent rebasing. I tend not to merge.

Setup:

```
$ git branch --show-current
master

$ git branch -b my_changes
<edit files>
```

When it's time to pull in changes from master:

```
git commit -am "Made changes"
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout my_changes
git rebase master
```

Is there a git workflow that could accomplish the same thing with fewer steps?

Comment: Do you want to always  update your local `master` branch as well?

Comment: Yes exactly! The local `master` should always be updated.

Comment: Not sure why you want an interactive rebase on the last step. If you just want to rebase `my_change` onto the updated `master`, the last two steps could be combined into `git rebase master my_changes`.

Comment: You could skip steps 2&4 by doing `git fetch` instead of pull and rebasing from origin/master. But then your local master wouldn't get updated, requiring a simple `git merge` (or pull) whenever you do switch to it

Comment: @jingx The interactive flag was just there due to habit. It's relevant when there are multiple branches stacked (my_changes_1, my_changes_2). I've removed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a git workflow that could accomplish the same thing with fewer steps?

Yes. The branch switching is unnecessary.  Stay on your branch, pull into master, and rebase onto master:

```
git commit -am "Made changes"
git fetch origin master:master
git rebase master
```

Or, since you probably don't need it, throw your local master away, and:

```
git commit -am "Made changes"
git fetch 
git rebase origin/master
```

Comment: `git fetch origin master:master` seems to be exactly what I needed to learn! Thank you. Are there any git-config settings that could simplify that with defaults?